# How can I select column via another MAX(datetime) column?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a summary query that will sum transactions totals, pull a most recent transaction date, and pull the most recent transactions quantity. What I have thus far follows:

```
SELECT
    A.bill_cust_code,
    A.product_code,
    A.pack_code,
    C.name,
    MAX(A.invoice_date) AS last_purchase_date,
    SUM(IF(A.invoice_date>DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y'),A.total_sales,0)) AS ytd_sales,
    SUM(IF(A.invoice_date<DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') AND A.invoice_date>DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y'),A.total_sales,0)) AS last_year_sales,
    A.source
FROM
    sales AS A
INNER JOIN
    prodware AS B ON (B.product_code = A.product_code AND B.pack_code = A.pack_code AND B.warehouse_code = A.warehouse_code)
INNER JOIN
    product AS C ON A.product_code=C.product_code
WHERE
    B.type='Y'
GROUP BY
    A.bill_cust_code,A.product_code,A.source
```

The `sales` table has quantity column. How can I pull the `sales`.`quantity` which corresponds to the `MAX(A.invoice_date)`?

**Sample Output**

```
+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| bill_cust_code | product_code | pack_code | name                          | last_purchase_date | ytd_sales  | last_year_sales | source    |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+
|              6 | DF2CARD      | 110       | ULTRA LOW SULFUR DIESEL 2 C/L | 2012-01-31         | 1022213.71 |     13663316.61 | Cardlock  |
|              6 | DF2CARD      | 104       | ULTRA LOW SULFUR DIESEL 2 C/L | 2010-12-06         |       0.00 |            0.00 | Wholesale |
|              6 | DFGRCARD     | 101       | GREEN DIESEL FUEL CARDLOCK    | 2006-08-31         |       0.00 |            0.00 | Cardlock  |
|              6 | DFGRPP       | LOC       | GREEN DIESEL FUEL PAC PRIDE   | 2008-04-15         |       0.00 |            0.00 | Cardlock  |
|              6 | DFRDCARD     | 108       | ULTRA LOW DYED DIESEL 2 C/L   | 2012-01-31         |   12678.35 |       136566.81 | Cardlock  |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

I would like another column `last_purchase_quantity` which is the quantity in the record returned by `MAX(A.invoice_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the above be a sub query and then select the additional info in the outer one.
I am not testing what I type cause i don't have the structure so please fix any mistake in typing.

```
SELECT sub_tab.bill_cust_code,
       sub_tab.product_code,
       sub_tab.pack_code,
       sub_tab.name,
       sub_tab.last_purchase_date,
       (select sales.quantity
        from sales
        where sales.invoice_date=sub_tab.last_purchase_date) as quantity,
       sub_tab.ytd_sales,
       sub_tab.last_year_sales,
       sub_tab.source
RFOM (

 SELECT
    A.bill_cust_code,
    A.product_code,
    A.pack_code,
    C.name,
    MAX(A.invoice_date) AS last_purchase_date,
    SUM(IF(A.invoice_date>DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y'),A.total_sales,0)) AS ytd_sales,
    SUM(IF(A.invoice_date<DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') AND A.invoice_date>DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y'),A.total_sales,0)) AS last_year_sales,
    A.source
FROM
    sales AS A
INNER JOIN
    prodware AS B ON (B.product_code = A.product_code AND B.pack_code = A.pack_code AND B.warehouse_code = A.warehouse_code)
INNER JOIN
    product AS C ON A.product_code=C.product_code
WHERE
    B.type='Y'
GROUP BY
    A.bill_cust_code,A.product_code,A.source
) sub_tab
```